# Manage multiple databases Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, connection, multiple-databases

The restriction is that I need to use multiple databases in my Android application. I need some information about a way how to manage multiple databases. When should I open and close particular database? 
When any instance of database should be a singleton? Should I open and then close my sqlite databases constanly after any operation or leave them opened and close them with app closing?
On startup I have to choose which database will be in use, i should be able to switch between databases.
PS I can`t use ContentProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Just create two different database..
You can do it with openDatabase and put different path for different DB.
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Thanks for reply. What about closing db? When and where should I do this??

Comment: You should close db on every onPause();